Why does a catalyst not instantaneously shift the position of equilibrium of a reaction?
I am a high school student so some of the concepts/explanations in this question may be slightly flawed.
I have just learnt the energy profile diagram, Maxwell Boltzmann distribution, and have done a bit of reading on the Arrhenius equation. I understand that adding a catalyst does not shift the position of equilibrium in any way, meaning the concentration graph of the products/reactants stay constant assuming the system was previously at equilibrium prior to the addition of a catalyst. This can also be explained using the explanation in the post that I have linked to below. However, observing the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution, this doesn't make sense to me.
Catalysts work by providing an alternate pathway for the reaction to occur, which has a lower activation energy. The energy profile diagram below (figure 1) shows this change. But this change in activation is equal for both the forward and reverse reaction, which when observed on the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution, can be observed as such (figure 2). However,  the number of additional reactant/product particles that have sufficient energies can clearly be different (as the areas under the graph change by different amounts, area being # of particles). Now because of this difference in additional product/reactant particles having sufficient energy to react, wouldn't the rates instantaneously change by different amounts when you add a catalyst, and wouldn't this consequently result in a change in concentrations, until equilibrium is re-established, at which point the system returns to how it was before the catalyst was added?


I have already viewed this explanation: Do catalysts increase the rate of exothermic reaction more in a reversible reaction?, but it doesn't explain the paradox that I have detailed above
Edit - Thank you all for the answers. Just to clarify, essentially, there were 2 errors with my explanation:

The Maxwell Boltzmann Distribution was drawn in a problematic way, and thus did not accurately demonstrate the proportionality between the 'additional number of particles with sufficient kinetic energy'
The Energy Profile Diagram is problematic as it is greatly simplified, where it actually has troughs and peaks, which mean the activation energy is dependant. Also, there is no relationship between the activation energies of the forward and reverse reaction, with different troughs and peaks. Therefore, when a catalyst is added, the activation energies are altered 'proportionally' so that the addition area under the Boltzmann cureve is proportional for both reverse and forward reaction (i.e. if 10% more particles now have sufficient energy for forward reaction, 10% also have sufficient energy for reverse.

A follow on question is: why do the activation energies change proportionally and not by the same amount, if the catalyst provides the same intermediate forward and reverse reactions (which implies that the activation energies should change equally)

If a catalyst shifted the position of the equilibrium, it would be a chemical equivalent of situation where both ways A to B and B to A went downhill. You could have system without a catalyst doing work getting from A to B, inserting a catalyst and making the system to do work, getting from B back to A.

So what's the flaw with the Maxwell Boltzmann explanation?

Of course when you drop in a catalyst the whole system changes, and the system needs to reestablish balance. And yes, there might be instantaneously "more molecules having sufficient activation energy", but they are all in the wrong path. These energy diagrams are not very good, since they all describe an elementary reaction, i.e. a single step. I know of no catalysed reaction where this is the case, and I would be surprised if it were even possible. In order to work as a catalyst, that molecule must form a complex with both reactants. In the energy diagram you should see a dip in the middle.

See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/108854/72973

If it is the Boltzmann approach you are after, you can begin from the Boltzmann distribution (note: not the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.), $$N_j = \frac{Ne^{-{E_j}/{K_B}T}}{\sum\limits_{i}^{z}e^{-{{E_i}/{K_B}T}}}$$
Which describes the population of particles at some state j, with energy $E_j$. The lower term is referred to commonly as the partition function, Q. The details of the partition function are not really relevant here, but just know that the value of the partition function for some specific system is effectively a constant at a constant temperature (which is a true condition in a catalyzed reaction). So, $$N_j = \frac{Ne^{-{E_j}/{K_B}T}}{Q}$$
If we consider now two equations for the number of particles $N_F$ from a sample of $N$ particles having energies equal to the activation energy $E_{\text{Af}}$ for an uncatalyzed forwards reaction, and another for all particles $N_B$ having a (much higher) activation energy $E_{\text{Ab}}$ for the uncatalyzed backwards reaction, we see $$N_F = \frac{Ne^{-{E_{\text{Af}}}/{K_B}T}}{Q}, \text{ } N_B = \frac{Ne^{-{E_{\text{Ab}}}/{K_B}T}}{Q}$$
For simplicity, consider that any particles having these energies or higher will be converted to products, therein establishing equilibrium in a system. Therefore, if we wanted to know the number of reactants in the system, we would find $N_B$ and vice versa for the total number of products in the system. The ratio of reactants to products is therefore, $$\frac{N_B}{N_F} = \frac{\frac{Ne^{-{E_{\text{Ab}}}/{K_B}T}}{Q}}{\frac{Ne^{-{E_{\text{Af}}}/{K_B}T}}{Q}}$$
Which you may simplify to $$\frac{N_B}{N_F} = \frac{e^{-{E_{\text{Ab}}}/{K_B}T}}{e^{-{E_{\text{Af}}}/{K_B}T}}$$ And further to $$\frac{N_B}{N_F}=e^{-(E_{\text{Ab}}-E_{{\text{Af}}})/{K_B}T}, \text{or } \frac{N_B}{N_F}=e^{-{\Delta E}/{K_B}T}$$
You said it yourself: when you add a catalyst, an alternative (very complex, usually) pathway is offered to all the particles in the system. Naturally, a reverse reaction is also offered, and the lowering of activation energy for both the forwards and backwards reaction is the same value from the original, uncatalyzed reaction. The number of particles at this new lower (forward) activation energy will be represented by $N_{CF}$, and similarly for the backwards reaction—let the change in the energies be represented by $\delta$. So, $$\frac{N_{CB}}{N_{CF}} = \frac{e^{-{E_{\text{Ab}}-\delta}/{K_B}T}}{e^{-{E_{\text{Af}}-\delta}/{K_B}T}}$$ Or, $$\frac{N_{CB}}{N_{CF}}=e^{-((E_{\text{Ab}}- \delta)-(E_{{\text{Af}}}- \delta))/{K_B}T} \text{ or, } \frac{N_{CB}}{N_{CF}}=e^{-(E_{\text{Ab}}-E_{{\text{Af}}})/{K_B}T}$$
Both derivations lead to the same equation, so we can conclude that the ratio of reactants to products remains the same, catalyzed or uncatalyzed. Ergo, the position of the equilibrium in a system is unaffected by a catalyst, no matter by how much the activation energy is lowered!
Intuitively, this also makes sense: think about why you add a catalyst to an equilibrium system. You want to speed up a reaction, not to drive a forward reaction to completion. For example, the Haber process, adding a catalyst only helps drive the formation of ammonia on a time scale that is viable for human production—the catalyst will never make more ammonia than is 'allowed' at the point of equilibrium.

Hi, I've edited my question above. Could you have another look at it?

@EthanHuang The activation energy does change by the same amount for both forwards and backwards reactions, say at the RDS. The number of particles with enough energy for the forwards and backwards reactions at equilibrium (as shown in my derivation above) also remains unchanged. The position of equilibrium is completely unaltered, it is just that the rate of the reaction (by virtue of having a lower $\text{E}_a$) is much faster, so equilibrium is established faster.

Two points to note, first that it takes a finite time for two reactants to diffuse together and second once together they have to have enough energy to react. To react the Boltzmann distribution is crucial and has the form $\sim\exp(-E/RT)$ where $E$ is energy, this can range from effectively zero (molecules not moving) to, technically infinity, but in practice, many times the average energy. All molecules have an energy in this range of energies due to randomly colliding with one another. The Boltzmann equation describes the chance of having energy $E$ and as $E$ gets bigger this chance becomes smaller and does so very rapidly indeed.
The fraction of molecules with energy $E$ above energy $E_A$, the activation energy barrier, is important and is normally very small. In a typical reaction at room temperature the average energy $E$ is far less than the activation energy and so only a minute fraction of all molecules colliding can react at each collision. The average energy at room temperature is $\approx 2.5$ kJ/mol and activation energies typically range from many tens to a few hundred kJ/mol. Thus many collisions and thus a long time may be needed before the activation energy by random chance is exceeded. (This is vital otherwise everything would have reacted long ago and I would not be writing this or you asking the question :) )
It follows from the distribution that one way to get more reaction is to increase the temperature so more molecules have energy above the activation energy, another way is to use a catalyst to lower $E_A$, by using a different reaction mechanism, and again more molecules have enough energy at a given temperature, to overcome the activation energy barrier and so the reaction is faster.
To answer your comment, the $\Delta H$ remains the same catalysed or not. If $E_f$ and $E_r$ are the forward and reverse activation energies the ratio of forward to reverse rate constants is $\displaystyle \frac{k_f}{k_r}\sim \frac{e^{-E_f/RT}}{e^{-E_r/RT}}$. Now suppose that the activation barrier energy is less when catalysed by an amount $\Delta$ then $\displaystyle \frac{k_{fc}}{k_{rc}}\sim \frac{e^{-(E_f-\Delta)/RT}}{e^{-(E_r-\Delta)/RT}}$ which is $\displaystyle \frac{e^{-E_f/RT}}{e^{-E_r/RT}}$ just as before, thus the equilibrium position is not changed as the ratio of rate constants is not changed.

Sorry, I might be missing something in your response, but why does this mean that the equilibrium does not shift position when a catalyst is added?

because  the ratio of rate constants via the Arrhenius eqn are unchanged.

I get that it works mathematically, but why doesn't it work with the Maxwell Boltzmann explanation?

What is important is the fraction of molecules with energy above the activation energy. As the activation energy is bigger when not catalysed than when it is catalyses, the reaction rate constants are bigger in the latter case as the same temperature.

Hi, I've edited my question above. Could you have another look at it?

This is because of a common misunderstanding in the use of catalysts. The common use of catalysts is to effect a change in the rate of a system that is NOT in equilibrium. The primary effect is to increase the rate of the forward reaction to produce product. When a reversible reaction reaches equilibrium the forward and reverse reactions are equal. This means that the Delta G of the reaction equals zero; reactants and products have equal free energies. Free energies are the combination of energy minimization and entropy maximization not just energy minimums. Adding a catalyst to a system at equilibrium does not change the free energy of the products or reactants so does not change the equilibrium position. Notice, that is the definition of a catalyst!
A system at equilibrium can be changed to shift the equilibrium. A common method is to physically remove a component shifting the equilibrium in that direction. A second method is to change the temperature inducing a change in the equilibrium constant. A third method is to add or remove energy or work on or by the system. These changes happen if a system is at equilibrium or equilibrium is approachable; in most cases a catalyst or sufficient energy is needed for the system to be at or near equilibrium. A common example of the latter is the electrolysis of water to give hydrogen and oxygen or the reversal using hydrogen and oxygen in a fuel cell to generate electricity. In both cases catalytic electrodes are needed to promote attainment of equilibrium or steady state electrode operation. The energy input is controllable for the reaction to be at equilibrium or to proceed in either direction.
A catalyst works by forming an intermediate compound or complex that is of lower energy than the activated complex or intermediates formed in the uncatalyzed reaction. This means that more molecular collisions will have sufficient energy to react by this pathway. It does not change the energy distribution of the product or reactant molecules so has no effect on the position of equilibrium. A change in temperature increases reaction rates by changing the energy distribution of molecules, both reactants and products with a concomitant change in the equilibrium constant. There are "catalysts" that do perturb equilibrium by removing a product. This is observed in the differences in acid-catalyzed and base-initiated reactions such as ester hydrolysis and some aldol type reactions. The basic reaction conditions will remove acidic products preventing the reverse reaction and changing the equilibrium. This is not a true catalysis although it seems so in that it increases the rate of the forward reaction.

Thanks for the answer. I've asked the same question for the answer above, but why doesn't the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution explanation of 'changing rates disproportionally' work?

I think i see your question. If the Ea is lower it should affect the higher Ea more. This is more complex. First the catalyst does NOT affect the energy distributions. Second: what is important is the Gibbs free energy. the reaction in one direction is energy driven in the other entropy driven. The Arrhenius equation breaks this into the preexponential and the exponential.  At equilibrium deltaH = Tdelta S ponder this a while and think about what happens in a perturbation from equilibrium in each direction.

Hi, I've edited my question above. Could you have another look at it?

You are onto something but that is not usually the focus when introducing the utility of catalysts. For mixtures at equilibrium, one containing a catalyst will have a different distribution of compounds from one without. With binding to a catalyst the population of both reactant and product can decrease (total matter being conserved, after all), but this is usually negligible and not important insofar as catalysts are designed to alter kinetics and are typically present in sparse amounts. More importantly, as other answers have pointed out, the ratio of reactants to products is ideally independent of other species such as intermediates.
Catalytic intermediates ideally exist in a "sweet-spot" with reagents stabilized in a geometry on a reaction pathway (but not so stable that the reaction is inefficient: trapping reactants in very stable or excessively long-lived intermediates is not catalysis).
There are various ways of building a simple model of how catalysts work. Typically one draws an energy diagram and says that either (1) the energy of an intermediate (eg transition state) is lowered by the catalyst or (2) the catalyst provides a different path through the energy "landscape." This latter analogy is probably simplest. Catalysis provides alternate (faster) paths between reagents and products. If you insist on the first analogy, then it is important to keep in mind that the catalyst changes the energy of the intermediate, not that of the reagents or products. It therefore doesn't make sense to say that the fraction of both reagents and products with sufficient energy has changed. Such a view invokes the kinetic theory of gases and is closer to arguing that a catalyst increases the temperature, which is not quite right.
The diagram showing a Boltzmann distribution in which you identify points that correspond to the energy and probability of products or reagents is misleading. You should instead focus on the energy of the intermediate(s) on the path between reactants and products. It is such intermediates that are affected by catalysts.
An important related concept to understand kinetics and the response of a system to a change, provided it regains equilibrium, is that of detailed balance. It is intuitive: equilibrium requires that the rates of formation and removal of any species be equal. I recommend looking into this concept.
Look also into enzyme kinetics to see how different properties of reaction intermediates can be relevant. This is not a simple topic. A lot of effort (see Ref 1) has been expended in understanding how and whether enzymes "pick" different conformations or alter conformational distributions.
References

Changeux JP, Edelstein S. Conformational selection or induced fit? 50 years of debate resolved. F1000 Biol Rep. 2011;3:19. doi: 10.3410/B3-19. Epub 2011 Sep 1. PMID: 21941598; PMCID: PMC3169905.


Hi, I've edited my question above. Could you have another look at it?


[OP in comments] I get that it works mathematically, but why doesn't it work with the Maxwell Boltzmann explanation?

It works with the Boltzmann distribution if you plot it correctly. You need the fraction of collisions that are above a certain threshold. Typically, only a tiny fraction of collisions are productive. Most don't have enough energy. If you lower the activation energy, both forward and reverse rate speed up by the same factor (as explained mathematically in two other answers).

The figure posted by the OP is misleading, suggesting that about half of the collisions are productive. Also, it is a plot of the speed of reactants rather than the energy of collisions, so the curve has a different shape.




[OP] However, the number of additional reactant/product particles that have sufficient energies can clearly be different (as the areas under the graph change by different amounts, area being # of particles).

If you have the correct graph, this does not happen. At a given temperature, lowering the activation energy by a given amount increases the rate by a constant factor, no matter what the activation energy is.

Hi, I've edited my question above. Could you have another look at it?
